# How to change the position of column in postgresql without dumping

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know the only workaround is to dump the table and then recreate the whole database with correct positioning of the required columns.

But the problem is one of the columns is a foreign key to many tables in the database so it would not be possible to just delete the whole table. Also I cannot delete any column as the foreign key column lies to the last of the table. Please give me a solution.

If this question is a duplicate please give me the link to the correct answer.

edit: for more clarification i want to add rows using the insert command and the problem is the second last column is of the type serial. My main aim is to not touch the serial column while giving the insert command

Comment: Could you please explain why you want to change the column's position?. You could create a view with the desired column position you want and use it or if you are using windows try https://fishcodelib.com/database.htm to change column position

Comment: because i want to add rows using the insert command and the problem is the second last column is of the type serial. My main aim is to not touch the serial column while giving the insert command

Comment: You can easily handle columns in an insert statement. `insert into table( type columns name with comma seperation and exclude the serial column) value(put corresponding values)`

Comment: You can insert into spcific columns: INSERT INTO table (column1, column3, column6) VALUES ('data1', 'data2', 'data6');

Comment: Ohh thanks that did not come to my mind XD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a custom insert statement,

For example,

Your table looks like this,

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."ada" (
    
    "trandate" date, 
    "locname" text, 
    "totusers" integer, 
    "actusers" integer, 
    "datausage" integer, 
    "issues" integer, 
    "id" serial PRIMARY KEY, 
    "issuessolved" integer
);
```

and the insert statement can be written as

```
INSERT INTO "public"."ada" (
    "trandate"
    ,"locname"
    ,"totusers"
    ,"actusers"
    ,"datausage"
    ,"issues"
    ,"issuessolved"
    )
VALUES (
    < trandate
    ,date >
    ,< locname
    ,text >
    ,< totusers
    ,integer >
    ,< actusers
    ,integer >
    ,< datausage
    ,integer >
    ,< issues
    ,integer >
    ,< issuessolved
    ,integer >
    );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude.